# passing execute shell data between build steps in jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Have 2 different execute shells in jenkins and need to pass a variable from one to another

Code below shows what i have tried

Shell script #1

```
export storedBanner=$(curl http://my.network:8080/boardmessage | jq -r .[0].message|sed 's/<[^>]*>//g') 

echo $storedBanner > ~/stored.txt

curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"message\":\"<h3>Test message<h3>\"}" http://my.network:8080/boardmessage
```

Shell script #2

```
export storedBanner= $(cat ~/stored.txt)

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"message\":\"<h4>${storedBanner}<h4>\"}" http://my.network:8080/boardmessage
```

I want that the exported message to be stored and passed down to 2nd shell script however this doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global variable to do that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, I figured it out with the file and it turns out i used the wrong syntax

Putting this in the shell script #2 worked :)

```
    storedBanner=$(<banner.txt)
```